# Related posts by tag name

Tags: django, django-views

i want to show related posts by tag name However i got the error " `get() returned more than one Tag -- it returned 2!"`

```
def post_detail(request,slug):
        post=get_object_or_404(Post,slug=slug)
        comments=Comment.objects.filter(post=post,reply=None,statusc=2).order_by('-date')
        comment_count=len(Comment.objects.filter(post=post, statusc=2))
        tag=get_object_or_404(Tag,post=post)
        related_item=Post.objects.filter(tag__tag_name__icontains=tag.tag_name,status=2).order_by('-created_date').distinct()[:3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just query like:

```
def post_detail(request,slug):
    post=get_object_or_404(Post,slug=slug)
    comments=Comment.objects.filter(post=post,reply=None,statusc=2).order_by('-date')
    comment_count=len(comments)

    related_items = Post.objects.filter(
        tag__post=post
    ).order_by('-created_date').distinct()[:3]
    # ...
```

Or if you want to exclude the current post:

```
def post_detail(request,slug):
    post=get_object_or_404(Post,slug=slug)
    comments=Comment.objects.filter(post=post,reply=None,statusc=2).order_by('-date')
    comment_count=len(comments)

    related_items = Post.objects.exclude(pk=post.pk).filter(
        tag__post=pos
    ).order_by('-created_date').distinct()[:3]
    # ...
```

It is also better to perform a `len(..)` on the `comments`, since that will result in making a query to fetch the comments, whereas using two separate queries, will hit the database twice.

Comment: The solution in the comment upper worked. I would record it your answer thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As per [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get), `get()` is used for retrieving 1 item. If there are multiple items, here there could be multiple tags used in single `Post`, it will throw error.

So, you can change it like this:

```
 tags=Tag.objects.filter(post=post)
 related_item=Post.objects.filter(tag__in=tags,status=2).order_by('-created_date').distinct()[:3]
```